# Stl-Format File Search Engine Not Preforming Searches Correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, search, stl-format

New to programming, with the help of chat gpt created a html, css, and js search engine that uses Thingiverse API to search for STL-Format files based on characters.

Problem is that at least from what I can see, it's pulling a ceartian number of random files off of thingiverse and then filtering those files based on the characters someone searched. From what I can see, the ammount of files is based on `const maxResultsPerPage = 100;`. 90% of the time this leads to searches with no results (very bad)

I can change that number so it searches more files yet then it becomes very, very slow. There are millions of files on Thingiverse so I need to find a way for it to preform searches effectively so it can find related files better.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>STL Search</title>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>STL Search</h1>

  <div id="searchContainer">
    <label for="searchInput">Enter characters:</label>
    <input type="text" id="searchInput" oninput="handleSearchInput()">
    <button onclick="performSearch()">Search</button>
  </div>

  <div id="searchResults"></div>

  <script>
    let debounceTimer;
    const cache = {};

    function debounce(func, delay) {
      clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
      debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
        func();
      }, delay);
    }

    function handleSearchInput() {
      debounce(performSearch, 300); // Adjust the delay as needed (e.g., 300ms)
    }

    async function performSearch() {
      const characters = document.getElementById('searchInput').value;
      const searchResultsContainer = document.getElementById('searchResults');

      if (cache[characters]) {
        displaySearchResults(cache[characters]);
        return;
      }

      try {
        searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '<p>Loading...</p>'; 
        const apiKey = 'API key goes here'; 
        const maxResultsPerPage = 100;
        const apiUrl = `https://api.thingiverse.com/search?q=${characters}&type=things&access_token=${apiKey}&per_page=${maxResultsPerPage}`;
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl);
        const data = await response.json();

        const filteredResults = data.hits.filter(result => result.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(characters.toLowerCase()) !== -1);

        searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '';
        cache[characters] = filteredResults; 
        displaySearchResults(filteredResults);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
        searchResultsContainer.innerHTML = '<p>Error fetching data</p>'; 
      }
    }

    function displaySearchResults(results) {
      const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('searchResults');
      resultsContainer.innerHTML = '';

      if (results.length === 0) {
        resultsContainer.innerHTML = '<p>No results found</p>';
      } else {
        results.forEach(result => {
          const resultElement = document.createElement('div');
          resultElement.classList.add('result');
          resultElement.innerHTML = `
            <a href="${result.public_url}" target="_blank">
              <img src="${result.thumbnail}" alt="${result.name}">
              <p>${result.name}</p>
            </a>
          `;
          resultsContainer.appendChild(resultElement);
        });
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Pagnation and getting help from Chat GPT